# What would be an elegant way to pass a token to my Angular 4 app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, authentication

I have following implementation:

**Frontend**: localhost:4200 (this is the Angular app)

**Backend**: localhost:3000 (this is my REST API running on Node.js & Express)

--

**Step 1.** In the Angular app the user clicks a link which redirects him to my REST API (localhost:3000/auth/steam).

**Step 2.** My REST API redirects him to an OpenID Provider (Steam) where he logs in.

**Step 3.** On successful login the OpenID Provider redirects the user back to my backend server together with the user data. My backend server saves this data in a DB and creates a JWT (JSON web token) containing the user data.

**Step 4.** Redirecting the user to the frontend together with the token...

this is the part where I don't really know what an elegant way to do this would be. I thought of passing the token as a URL parameter (?token=...) but this would be a bit unsafe since the token would be visible in the URL.

Is there a better way of doing it? Thanks :)

Comment: Store the token in local storage. Send the JWT token in the header: Authorization: Bearer <token>

Comment: That was my first approach as well, but I cannot find any resources on how to set headers before a redirect in node.js/express which makes me think that this is not possible

Comment: The auth header is already set on the request coming back from the IdP (its a POST to your URL). Your angular app just needs to read it and store it. Every subsequent request, add it to the header.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my implementation. :) The IdP redirects the user back to my backend server (localhost:3000/auth/steam/return) where passport.js handles the request. I save the data in my db, create a JWT and now I want to redirect the user with the token to my frontend Angular App

Comment: How did you solve this problem @verize? I'm looking into a similar scenario and pondering my options...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way will be to sent it in `Http Headers`.
And the best way to do that is to use `HttpClientModule` for http requests. 
Also this module provides `Interceptor` functionality in next way:

```html
providers: [
      ...
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
]

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const copy = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.authService.getToken())});
        return next.handle(copy);
    }
}
```